# Adding Pagination in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

How to add pagination in the Lightning web Component and restrict the result of the SOQL upto 25 results per page?

```
Query Restriction
```

Comment: Where do the upvotes come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange!

Here's an [example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreaminvest-lwc/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/paginator/paginator.html) from Sample Gallery's Dreaminvest.

There's another [example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/paginator/paginator.js) from LWC Recipes.

Keep in mind you need to handle these JS events in the parent component, this pagination component is designed to be used interchangeably, making it quite useful.

To really understand, I suggest you check out the LWC recipes app in your development environment.